# How to roll-up a column of data and separate values by a delimiter?

Tags: sas

I need to transform from `output1` to `output2`.

The first column is how I'd like to break up the roll-ups. The second column is what I'd like to roll-up. Separate the roll-up values by a `/`.

**Output1**:

```
data output1;
    input id $ app $;
    datalines;
    id001 app11
    id001 app12
    id002 app21
    id002 app22
    id002 app23
    id003 app31
    id003 app32
    id004 app41
    ;
```

**Output2:**

```
id001 app11/app12
id002 app21/app22/app23
id003 app31/app32
id004 app41
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
PROC TRANSPOSE DATA=TRAIL1 OUT=TTRAIl1(DROP=_NAME_) PREFIX=COL;
    VAR app; BY id; 
RUN;

%LET NCOLS = 3; *you can get this from VTABLE

DATA RES(DROP=i COL1 - COL&NCOLS.);
    SET TTRAIl1;
    LENGTH RES $256; 
    ARRAY COLS{*} COL1 - COL&NCOLS.; 
    RES = COL1;
    DO i = 2 TO DIM(COLS);
       IF MISSING(COLS(i)) eq 0 THEN RES = CATS(RES,'/',COLS(i));
    END;
RUN;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
data testin;
 input id $ app $;
 datalines;
 id001 app11
 id001 app12
 id002 app21
 id002 app22
 id002 app23
 id003 app31
 id003 app32
 id004 app41
 ;
 run;

 data new;
   length app $ 50;
   length app0 $ 50; 
   set testin ;
     if id0 eq id then app = trim(app)||'/'||trim(app0);
   id0 = id;
   app0 = app;
   retain id0 app0;
 run;
 proc sort data=new; by descending app0; run;
 proc sort data=new (DROP=app0 id0) nodupkey; by id; run;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work too.
    data output1;
     input id $ app $;
     datalines;
     id001 app11
     id001 app12
     id002 app21
     id002 app22
     id002 app23
     id003 app31
     id003 app32
     id004 app41
     ;
     run;

```
 /*allows the next data step to use first. last. processing for the retain*/
 proc sort data=output1;
 by id app;
 run;

data output2 (drop=app rename=(app2 = app));

 set output1;
 length app2 $24.;
 /*allows the value of app2 to be held to the next observation*/
 retain app2;
 /*begins first/last processing in the data step*/
 by id;

if first.id then app2 = app;
else app2 = catx('/',app2,app);
/*if you comment the next line you can see what the if/else is doing*/
if last.id;

run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code

```
proc transpose data = TRAIL1 out=trail_trans(DROP=_NAME_) prefix=COL_ ;
    var app; by id; 
run;

data output2(keep=id out_var);
length out_var $500.;
set trail_trans;
    COL_temp="";                               *this temp column is to handle if there is no data in 'app'(column) and next line throws error;
    out_var = catx ("/",OF COL:);
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Writing this from my phone so apologies for the lack of indentation.

```
proc sort data=trail1;
by id app;
run;

data want (drop=app);
do until (last.id);
set trail1;
by id;
length apps $100;
apps=catx('/', apps, app);
end;
run;
```